# Render failure — GPU

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, gpu

So I'm trying to render using my GPU (Intel HD Graphics 4000 1536 MB on MacOS), but every time it fails. I went to the system preferences, checked "CUDA" and it selected my graphics card (so it would seem it's supported), yet when I go to render it "fails to load the render kernel." and tells me to view the console for further information. But when I check the python console, there is absolutely nothing related to the subject—rendering hasn't even modified it.

What am I doing incorrectly? Am I wrong, and my graphics card really is incompatible with Cycles? Or is it something else?

Comment: CUDA is NVidia proprietary technology. For GPU acceleration you need either NVidia or AMD graphics card

Comment: AMD GPU rendering is done using opencl, this should also work for Intel GPU's.

Comment: By the way, it means the system console, not the python console. *Window > Show System Console* on windows. On other OS's you'll have to start Blender from the terminal.